# script started in .xinitrc stays in processes

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, xinit

I have made a little startup bash-script to run before my wm starts. Unfortunately
after X and WM is started this script is still listed in the in `htop` and I don't have a clue why...

this is the startup-script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Bind Multimedia Keys with xbindkeys
xbindkeys

#Turn X-Screensaver off
xset -dpms; xset s off

#Set Cursor to Arrow-Shape
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

# Start Compton for compositing
compton --config ~/.config/compton.conf -b

# Set Wallpaper
feh --bg-fill ~/pictures/makoto-shinkai_00412767.jpg

# Start Dropbox
[ -e /usr/bin/dropboxd ] && /usr/bin/dropboxd &

# Start Emacs-Daemon
#/usr/bin/emacs --daemon

exit
```

and this is my .xinitrc

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

$HOME/bin/xstartup

# i3 is kept as default
session=${1:-i3}

case $session in
    bspwm             ) exec bspwm;;
    i3|i3wm           ) exec i3;;
    hlwm              ) exec herbstluftwm;;
    # No known session, try to run it as command
    *) exec $1;;
esac
```

Comment: Most of your programs in the script should finish quickly. I'm not familiar with the `compton`  command, but: `feh` could be the blocking process. It is not detached (`&`) and it doesn't background by its own. I hence don't understand how the script ever returns (and lauches the WM as you say). Try to put a `&` after `feh` and let us know if that helps.

Comment: Is `$HOME/bin/xstartup` the script shown on top?